# how to perform dynamic increment for ebs volumes in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I have a requirement that, we want to increase the ebs volume size dynamically and friends please guide me how to perform this operation.

Comment: Welcome, you should provide information about what you have tried so far.

Comment: up to now I have done it manually but I want it to be done automatically

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't enough information.  It doesn't happen "automatically."  You have to write code that tests the condition that you want to trigger a change, and generates the necessart API requests and performs the relevant filesystem resize.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Lambda function using [AWS EC2 SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#modifyVolume-property) to increase the volume size based on your conditions.

Examples:
Calling the modifyVolume operation

```
var params = {
  VolumeId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  DryRun: true || false,
  Iops: 0,
  Size: 0,
  VolumeType: standard | io1 | gp2 | sc1 | st1
};
ec2.modifyVolume(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: can you please guide me how to perform this operation..as i am new to aws@ashan